# Typo3 page doesn't show up at front end. Error 500 - No TypoScript record found

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typoscript

I am quite a newbie to Typo3 but like to test it very much for publishing web sites. Do have some basic knowledge about building web sites with HTML, Javascript and CSS.

Now I'd like to see which nice things Typo3 can do. Installed the latest **Version 12.4.10** a couple of days ago at my webspace host's site (strato.de). Didn't need to to any specific configuration. That was done by my host provider automatically which was nice.

Since then I got familiar with the nuts & bolts of Typo3. I defined a root page with headers and some text. Marked it as "Root" and "Visible". Just like it was said in the Typo3 online documentation.

But when I like to see how my test page will be rendered at the front end by clicking at "View" a new page opens prompting **Error 500 "The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No TypoScript record found!"**.

After doing quite a research I found out that some sort of **TypoScript on root level** needs to be created. I was prompted to the TypoScript tool were I added a Root TypoScript record to my test page. So far so good.

There is no error throwing anymore which is good but it's just a lapidar **"Hello World!"** displaying at the front end now. However my test page still doesn't show up. It's slowly becoming despairing. I tried several things e.g. deleting that TypoScript section in that TypoScript record responisble for Hello World but nothing helped.

So if anybody has some idea of what to do I would appreciate a lot. Still don't want to give up and deleting my Typo3 installation again because I am much convinced it is a very powerful tool.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Usually you've to create a sitepackage, and details can be found here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/12.4/en-us/Index.html.
You might start with the introduction package: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/12.4/en-us/IntroductionPackage/Index.html#introductionpackage-index or verify directly this:  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/12.4/en-us/NextSteps/Index.html#next-steps

Comment: David, 
many thanks for your quick response. As I see I obviously got a total misunderstanding of what Typo3 actually is. I thought you can use it like a click & drop tool to create frontend design elements without utilizing HTML or CSS. Everybody speaks of Typo3 for creating web sites but it seems to me now like a CMS only - however a very powerful one. If you still have to use HTML, etc. coding Typo3 is obviously of no use for my small website projects. As I said, I was looking for a quick way of designing web pages and not for a highly sophisticated CMS. I will keep Typo3 in mind however.

Comment: you can install the extension bootstrap_package and can nearly directly start entering and displaying content.
In the page records you just have to select the layouts and include the TS config and before you've to select the static template in the template record.

Comment: Me again: found a great online course which explains binding bootstrap into T3 without any programming just by leveraging Template feature and wow I can see my sample page online now in perfect shape. No "Hello World" and no "Error 500" anymore. 
Unfortunately it is in German language. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qAJCkz-Rk2Y&list=PL3rp1RjcIPQgYE5oIROBYuDdFScMEhxis&index=8

Comment: Great, congrats! Possible that there are English videos too, but I don't know - especially about this exact topic.

Comment: German is fine though - it's my mother language :-)